# JSoup not showing correct text

Tags: java, jsoup

So I wanted to create a Java App which crawls the Songname of a website called chillstep.info and saves it into a .txt file. However JSoup prints this out:
`<div id="titel">
 ♫
</div>`

Here's the code:

```
public class Crawltitle {

    public static void getTitle() throws IOException{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://chillstep.info/").get();
        String title = doc.getElementById("titel").outerHtml();
        System.out.println(title);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        getTitle();
    }
}
```

Is this problem because of the website (if yes, why and how to solve that problem) or JSoups?

Comment: sorry, was wrong in my first assumption... I will create the right answer.

Comment: @Volkan why do you use `titel`  if you want to get `title` .confused !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is loaded dynamically via

```
http://chillstep.info/jsonInfo.php
```

You still can use Jsoup to get this, if you ignore the usually allowed content type:

```
Connection con = Jsoup
   .connect("http://chillstep.info/jsonInfo.php")
   .ignoreContentType(true);    
Response res = con.execute();
String rawJSON = res.body();
```

Note that I did not use the JSoup parser. So you might as well have used any other library to get HTTP content, like Apache HtmlClient or such.

At this point you can parse the answser with a json library of your choice. Or do it "by hand" since it is so simple:

```
String title = rawJSON.replaceAll(".*:\"([^\"]*).*","$1");
```

Comment: i think you are messing with `title ` and `titel`

Comment: Oh I see! May I ask how you found out that it is loaded dynamically? Anyways thank you very much!

Comment: look at the network tab in the browser when the site loads

Comment: @FastSnail yes, i was confused. But I revised my answer completely.